# Bloch sphere visualization using Cirq, ProjectQ, PyQuil

Tags: programming, cirq, pyquil, projectq

Is there a way to visualize the Bloch sphere using Cirq, ProjectQ, and/or PyQuil, as it is possible using `plot_bloch_vector` in Qiskit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer *seems* to be "no" for all three. From what I can find, Cirq and PyQuil default to QuTiP for Bloch sphere visualization, and ProjectQ does not have any examples to go off of, nor can I find the functionality in their GitHub.

- TensorFlow Quantum, which primarily uses Cirq (since they are both owned by Google), used `qutip.Bloch` in [this binary classification tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/blob/research/binary_classifier/binary_classifier.ipynb) instead of any Cirq function, implying that Cirq does not have an equivalent.
- Rigetti, which owns PyQuil, used `qutip.Bloch` in [this training material](https://github.com/markf94/rigetti_training_material/blob/master/session_2/tutorial_II_quantum_gates.ipynb) instead of any PyQuil function, and in [this intro tutorial](https://github.com/rigetti/pyquil/blob/v2.22.0/docs/source/intro.rst), implying that PyQuil does not have an equivalent.
- ProjectQ does not have any publicly visible Bloch sphere visualization tools in [their Github](https://github.com/ProjectQ-Framework/ProjectQ), either. But their software already uses the IBM quantum experience, so I believe they would default to `qiskit.plot_bloch_vector`.

These are my findings based on briefly poking around in each of these softwares’ open-source. If there are any Cirq/ProjectQ/PyQuil contributors out there, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Cirq maintainer here: yes, Cirq currently does not have a Bloch sphere plot but we are aiming to implement one in the coming months. You can use [cirq.bloch_vector_from_state_vector](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/qis/bloch_vector_from_state_vector) to calculate the bloch vector for a given qubit in a given state though.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!